# Website to know about books something similar to IMDB for movies?

Tags: book

I just started reading books I have completed chethan bhagath's(Indian author) books and other books  like Godfather,notebook. I want to know what are new/good books i can read. Is there any website to know about good books? Similar to IMDB website. Instead of movies i want to know about books.
*Edit: The website which list the books according to user rating*

Comment: This question can potentially result in a nearly-endless list of reading/book websites, something discouraged on Stack Exchange sites. So that we can leave this question open, could you narrow down what you're looking for a little? For example, do you want user ratings, or is it more important that such a website have "official" data (publisher, editor, etc.)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about reading (specifically what to read next/developing a reading list) not writing.

Comment: This question is being discussed on meta: http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/987/1993

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 answers:

1 .  Amazon reviews: Amazon has a very good system, where it shows you books similar to the one you bought. There are also lists created by users, which give the books similar to the current one they enjoyed.

You don't have to be registered with Amazon to look at the book recommendations.

2 .  [Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/) - Though I personally haven't used it- does a similar thing. Unlike amazon, the lists here are driven entirely by users. You can join groups, become friends with other users and share book recommendations etc.

In both these websites, you can also click on a book reviewers ID, and see which others book they reviewed. Chances are, you may also like those books.

There are other websites similar to Goodreads, but it is the most popular one, so I suggest you start there.

Comment: I am using Goodreads now... Its good:)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bit late, but there is a brand new web that could be interesting for you.

If what you want is something similar to IMDB, I am using since some weeks a site called abookado: http://abookado.com

Hope it helps

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Goodreads is my choice for searching books, when you add your friends, it is very useful to share recommendations and your reading history, I'm sure that you would love it!

I sometimes read [NY Times](http://www.nytimes.com/pages/books/index.html) book reviews too.